# AJP Proxy settigs with mod_rewrite

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, proxy, apache2, ajp

I have a problem with AJP proxy settings.

**Versions of SW**
Oracle Linux Server 6.5, Apache 2.2.15, Apache Tomcat 7.0.29, tomcat-connectors-1.2.37-src.

**Expected behaviour**
`With slash at the end of URL

http:/@/name.company.local/application/ --> http:/@/name.company.local:8080/application/ 
It works => OK


Without slash at the end of URL
http:/@/name.company.local/application -> http:/@/name.company.local:8080/application 
It does NOT work => K.O.


With path after app name
http:/@/name.company.local/some/path -> http:/@/name.company.local:8080/application/some/path 
It does NOT work => K.O.`

**Apache Log file** (var/log/httpd/name.company.local-error_log)

```
[Fri Dec 13 10:48:33 2013] [error] [client 10.0.100.26] File does not exist: /var/www/name.company.local/application
[Fri Dec 13 10:48:33 2013] [error] [client 10.0.100.26] File does not exist: /var/www/name.company.local/application
```

**AJP proxy settings** (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ajp.conf)

`ProxyRequests Off
 
<Proxy *>

  Order deny,allow
 
  Deny from all
 
  Allow from localhost
 
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /application ajp://localhost:8009/application

ProxyPassReverse /application ajp://localhost:8009/application`

**Apache settings** (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd)

`NameVirtualHost *:80

    NameVirtualHost *:443
 
    ServerName name.company.local

 
    <VirtualHost *:80>
 
      ServerAdmin webmaster@company.cz
 
      DocumentRoot /var/www/name.company.local
 
      ServerName name.company.local
 
      ServerAlias application


      RewriteEngine On
 
      RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"

      RewriteLogLevel 9
 
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.local$
 
      RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http:/@/name.company.local/$1 [R=301]

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application/

      RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /application/$1

      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{User-Agent}i\"" appspecial

      ErrorLog logs/name.company.local-error_log

      CustomLog logs/name.company.local-access_log appspecial
</VirtualHost>`

Can you tell me, what is wrong? Or how can I debug it?

With regards

Nautil

P.S. **Due to low reputation at Stack Overflow (I'm a newbie) I could not use more than 2 links, therefore I had to replace valid HTTP protocol prefix with http:/@/.**

Answer (score 0):

I have solved *Without slash at the end of URL* problem by change of rewrite rule:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /application/$1`

I have also solved  *With path after app name* problem, again with modification of rewrite rule:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application

RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://name.company.local/application/$1`